# Zend framework installation - need clarification

Tags: php, zend-framework

I've seen lots of videos and instructions on how to install zend framework on wamp and other similiar local host environments.  I've also seen lots of references, including here, that mention you don't need to 'install' zend, it just needs to be included in the php files to work.

As I *think* I understand it, installing zend on localhost environments will allow you to utilize certain tools that for example automate the creation of projects and gets the most out of the framework. I'm assuming that to then use these projects in a web host environment, you simply need to upload a specific project's files and ensure the zend files are in place and included in the directories.

Are my assumptions correct? I'm still trying to grasp the basics of this one and haven't found clarifications in my google searches.

Comment: The only time an "installation functionality" cannot be simulated by copying/creating folders is when the system (think of the registry) or the software (think, location of non-system-path located functionality) needs a script to determine and save certain configuration settings. Most PHP systems don't need this per se, although things like DB connections and other non-derived settings will need to be provided.

Comment: So in other words, an "installation functionality" may, in some cases, only copy files and create folders, not do anything "magical" or "computed and stored".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything you wrote is correct. It helped me to think of Zend Framework as a library of components rather than as a program you need to install. As long as your application has access to that library of components, Zend Framework is installed. This doesn't address any of the configuration tasks you'll need in Bootstrap and/or application.ini, but should clear up installation.

Regarding the automated creation of projects and project elements (controllers, actions, etc.) this feature is available via Zend_Tool and is typically used only during development, so it shouldn't come into play once you've ported from your localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Automated creation of the projects is far not the main feature of Zend.
The majority of the php frameworks are about providing the best infrastructure for complying to MVC design pattern, about object relational mapping, security enhancements etc.

And yes, the whole project tree is what you'd need to carry around for deployments.